# Creating child MVC application within parent MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I am building out a very large set of web applications for a client, and one of the requirements is that they are done using C# within the ASP.NET MVC framework.

I have creating my main "launchpad" area, which serves as the place the user logs in to gain access to the various web applications.  This launch pad area is itself a MVC application, and everything for it is working fine so far.  I have been able to set up Azure authentication, etc.

My problem is that I am now creating the first of many web applications that will launch from this launchpad app.  [I followed the steps (as many as applied to me) found here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/307467/how-to-create-an-asp-net-application-from-multiple-projects-for-team-d), however, I am not able to access my child application.

My directory structure goes like this

> C:\LaunchPad\ ** root directory for main launchpad MVC application
>   C:\LaunchPad\ChildApplication\  ** root directory for first child MVC
>   application

When I try to browse to /ChildApplication from within my launchpad, it throws an IIS Forbidden: Access Denied error.

Could anyone give me some guidance on how to properly set this up?  The requirements for me are that the resources from the launchpad application should be available (Class objects, etc) to all Child applications.  The Session created in the launchpad application must be visible to the Child applications as well.

**If someone could at least inform me if what I am trying to do is possible, that would be great.  Any ideas on alternative setups would be great too!**

Comment: To whoever marked for close, please explain why.  I thought I structured my questions very clearly.

Comment: You should be able to communicate with other app by adding a reference to them.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that directly because:

1. Web projects are always created in their own IIS application directories.
2. These directories do not share resources with each other.

If you still want to then there is a work around that Microsft suggests. Check out the "**Make Multiple Visual Studio .NET Projects Participate in the Same Web Application**" section [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/307467/how-to-create-an-asp-net-application-from-multiple-projects-for-team-d).